# IntelliJ-like copy buffer on vim?

Tags: intellij-idea, vim, clion, jetbrains-ide

I'm aware of yank/put registers and the like, but I find them cumbersome to use. I've been looking around online for a similar item to the "visual copy buffer" that is available in JetBrains IDEs. I.e. when you press <kbd>Cmd + Shift + V</kbd> you get:

[image]

That is - I would like to map or create a plugin that with one key combo can remind me of my previous yanks - I'm hoping such a thing exists - If not I will just write the plugin for it.

Comment: Not a full answer, but you can call `:reg` to see the current contents of every register.

Comment: Ah! Good input, I wasn't aware of that command (though I suppose it should be obvious). I'm hoping there is a solution that pops a menu like: https://i.imgur.com/SefnzqV.png If not I guess I should start investigating writing vim plugins!

Comment: I'm not aware of how to do that, but I'm sure it would be possible. If you want to get advice on writing vim plugins, a great place for it would be [vi.stackexchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com). Asking a more specific question about how to get that pop up would probably be well received, and there are lots of vim fanatics there who could help. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `:reg[isters]` directly, use it in a custom mapping, or look for [a plugin](https://github.com/svermeulen/vim-easyclip).

But such a feature is too generally useful to be restricted to a single program or re-implemented in various different ways across multiple programs. I'd suggest using a system-wide clipboard manager instead.

On macOS I use [ClipMenu](http://www.clipmenu.com/). On Windows I recommend [ClCl](http://www.nakka.com/soft/clcl/index_eng.html). On Linux I have no idea [which one](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/clipboard#List_of_clipboard_managers) to recommend.